# Blazor server validation errors how to style controls not bound directly to the model

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a number of controls inside an `EditForm`.

Most of those controls are bound to a property of a model using `@bind-Value`.

That means that during validation if I add a message to the message store, using an expression that corresponds to the same property that the control is bound to, the validation system will place a CSS "invalid" class on the control so that I can style the control that is bound to the property that is in violation:

```
<EditForm EditContext="@MyEditContext">
   <InputSelect id="ddMyProperty" @bind-Value="MyModel.MyProperty" class="form-select"/>
</EditContext>

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyModel.MyProperty))
{
    _validationMessages.Add(() => MyModel.MyProperty, "My Property is empty.");
}
```

How do I do that with controls that are not bound directly to the model, such as `InputFile` controls?

```
<InputFile id="fileUpload" class="form-control" accept="@MyModel.AllowedTypes" OnChange="@file_OnChange"></InputFile>

protected void file_OnChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    this.Model.MyFile = e.File;
}

if (this.Model.MyFile == null)
{
    _validationMessages.Add(() => Model.MyFile, "My File is empty."); //<--- This won't style my input control
}
```

**Edit:**

I think my question might not have been clear.  This is all wrapped in an EditForm, but normally, if you add a validation message and specify an accessor that is a property in your model that a control is also bound to, the control gets a css class called "invalid" so the control can be styled.  How do you get that same behaviour if the control doesn't have a value that can be directly bound to, like a FileInput control?

Comment: Why not just wrap an `EditForm` around it with an `EditContext`  You have a *Model*.

Comment: You can also use something like FluentValidation.  You can call validate whenever you like and display the results.  I can show you a quick example from your above code.

Comment: I think my question might not have been clear.  This is all wrapped in an EditForm, but normally, if you add a validation message and specify an accessor that is a property in your model that a control is also bound to, the control gets a css class called "invalid" so the control can be styled.  How do you get that same behaviour if the control doesn't have a value that can be directly bound to?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

I've use some basic validation code from another answer demoing how to change colours.  The `FieldIfentifier` is just an object/string pair to provide a unique identifier.

```cs
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<div class="@_validationCss p-4 m-2">
    <EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnSubmit="@OnSubmitHandler">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <div>
            <label class="form-label" >Enter name: </label>
            <InputText class="form-control" id="name" @bind-Value="_customer.Name" /><br />
        </div>
        <div class="text-end mb-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">submit</button>
        </div>
        <ValidationSummary />
    </EditForm>
</div>

<div class="m-2 text-end">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="AddAddressError">Add Address Error</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="ClearAddressError">Clear Address Error</button>
</div>
<div class="alert @(_validated ? "alert-success" : "alert-danger")">
    <p>Model valid: @_validated.ToString()</p>
</div>

@code {
    private EditContext? _editContext;
    private Customer _customer = new();
    private bool _validated = true;
    private string _validationCss => _validated ? "modified valid" : "invalid";
    private ValidationMessageStore? _addressValidationStore;


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _customer = new Customer();
        _editContext = new(_customer);
        _editContext.OnValidationStateChanged += this.OnValidationStateChanged;
        _addressValidationStore = new(_editContext);
    }

    protected void AddAddressError()
    {
        var fi = new FieldIdentifier(_customer, "Address");
        _addressValidationStore?.Clear(fi);
        _addressValidationStore?.Add(fi, "The Address ain't good!");
        _editContext?.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
    }

    protected void ClearAddressError()
    {
        var fi = new FieldIdentifier(_customer, "Address");
        _addressValidationStore?.Clear(fi);
        _editContext?.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
    }

    private void OnValidationStateChanged( object? sender, ValidationStateChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        if (_editContext is not null)
            _validated = _editContext.GetValidationMessages().Count() == 0;

        // This is an event so there's no built in call to StateHasChanged
        this.StateHasChanged();   
    }

    private void OnSubmitHandler()
    {
        _validated = _editContext?.Validate() ?? false;
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        [Required] public string? Name { get; set; }
        public Address? Address { get; set; }
    }
    public class Address
    {
    }

}
```